# Правильная приостановка php скрипта

Tags: php, apache, веб-программирование

Добрый день, есть php скрипт который обрабатывает в вечном цикле соединения по socket (передает посылки между клиентами), как правильно приостановить работу скрипта если клиенты не предают посылок (дабы не нагружать систему) ?

Comment: а скрипт использует select/poll ?

Comment: Сохраняю в массив ресурсы полученные через socket_accept.

Comment: Если ничего не перемудрили, то  socket_accept в отсутствие новых подключений будет просто заблокирован и потребление ресурсов CPU скриптом будет минимальное.